# Communicate with thread and find running time

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there is any mechanism in java through which we can communicate to the running thread and find from how much time it is running?

Comment: Hi!! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this is a Q&A site, where you post problematic code and errors and other users kindly point the issues in your code.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

to calculate time of processing, you can do like below:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//your process
long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long duration = finishTime - startTime;//unit is milisecond
```

Comment: I should run another function after the thread runnning for 3 seconds

Comment: So, you should to consider to use Timer to make sure the 3 seconds. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to measure how much CPU time is used by an individual thread, see this answer:

[CPU execution time in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467245/cpu-execution-time-in-java)