# Variable declaration in java

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, variable-declaration, cpu-time

How I can use the CPU time as variable in java where I need to define a variable with dynamic value increase with time pass
example

int cpuTime;
first:
cpuTime = 0 because but after 20 second cpuTime = 20 and after 60 second cpuTime= 60 and so on? where, i need to check some condition with time pass. 
example if cpuTime > p-10 do {}

Best regards

Comment: You can get its current value with `Syste.currentTimeMilis()`...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto, millis is not a CPU time though - it's wall time, what internal system clock produces. Although looking at the question, OP might've been asking about millis and not CPU time all along.

Comment: maybe this can help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7467299/6503002

Comment: If you're looking for an ever-increasing count of seconds, are you instead looking for *epoch time*?  You could start it at 0 by simply recording the initial value and subtracting it from further values.

Comment: Yes Mr David that is what i need. Can you write an example?

Answer (score -2):

```
final long startTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("something");
final long stopTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("endfunction:"+ (stopTime - startTime));
```