# Why is a finally block used when timing a method in Java?

Tags: java, timing

https://stackoverflow.com/a/180191

Here a method is timed by calling `System.nanoTime()` in a normal block, while the end time is called for in a finally block?

Was this only done to report a correct time even if the method throws an exception? or does guarantee even more: not only that it will be called but also right after the method (i.e. preventing task switching or similar...) ?

what is the motivation of using `final` modifiers here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reason to do this is to make sure that the second `nanoTime()` is called even in the presence of exceptions.

There are no guarantees related to task switching.

As to the `final` modifiers, I think they are just a matter of personal style, and have no effect on the timings. Like the person who wrote that answer, I often mark variables that are effectively constant as `final`.

Comment: and why are final modifiers used? the example assumes it will only be timed once?

Comment: @propaganda: Just a matter of personal style I suppose. Don't think they have any effect on the timings. I've updated the answer.

Comment: The `final` modifiers are a defensive programming practice (like `const` in C++). If you've marked the reference as final, you can't introduce a bug by changing it when you didn't mean to. It's especially useful with primitives and with immutable objects.

Comment: Also, note that entering and exiting the `try` block will incur a measurable overhead.