# method references count statistics in Android project

Tags: java, android, methods, plugins

For projects reasons I need to find out which methods of a class are referenced (used) and how many times. Lint gives me ability to find which are unused but I cannot find any tool to precise how many times methods are referenced. It could be an Android Studio plugin or a library (or any other way that prepares these statistics)

thanks in advance for your support

Answer (score 0):

You have to first step back and and clarify your requirements.

To determine how often a method is **used** within other pieces of code is trivial; any decent IDE allows you search your project/workspace for usage of methods.

But you are asking about **count** statistics. That is a **completely* different thing. An easy solution is to simply put static counters into your classes manually. But such self-grown solutions can turn pretty complex quickly; as people start asking for all kinds of solutions. Thus you might rather looking into profiling tools, such as [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444349/java-how-can-i-measure-method-call-times) for java in general, or specifically for Android: look [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/index.html).

Comment: You're right, so to precise my question:
I need a tool for an Android project that will determine how often a method is used with the projects code (with a narrowed package filter). It must be something programmatic rather than a key combination that searches method usages. My aim is to apply it on a large set of methods and have an output:

Class A -> method B: used 20 times
Class C -> method D: used 4 times
etc..

I've found a library that does that (and more) but it can't be used on Android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772229/reflections-library-returns-empty-list-in-android