# How to diagnostic SQL bottlenecks in Java EE

Tags: sql, performance, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

We're having some SQL bottlenecks, I guess it's due to transaction isolation.

We're gonna try debugging step-by-step our offending code and checking the database profiler to detect which resources are being blocked at a given time.

How would you diagnostic SQL bottlenecks on Java EE?

Comment: If you mention which DBMS you're using, you may get some specific suggestions on database-level tooling that can expose possible concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a quite classical method: measure the time used by each query and write in a debug file the timings, followed by the query. Then, run the application a few times, in normal usage conditions, and see the queries that take more time.

About timing in Java:
[How do I time a method's execution in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java)

Also notice that some SQL queries do take more time than others because of the quantity of data: for example, "SELECT" statements are common bottlenecks. A `SELECT * FROM userdata` statement takes much more time than a `SELECT name, surname FROM userdata` one, especially when you have lots of stored data.