# How to read plain html file from URLs faster?

Tags: java, html, performance, file, http

I need to "read" a lot of links with slightly different URLs for further parsing.
Using this code:

```
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "false");
    //System.out.println(http);
    //System.out.println(html);
    URL pageToRead = new URL(http);

    URLConnection yc = pageToRead.openConnection();
    yc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            yc.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(html);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        out.write(inputLine);
    }


    in.close();
    out.close();
```

Note about variables: `http` is String with the full URL. `html` is String with full file name.

**Two questions:**

1. How to change this code to read URLs faster?
2. Maybe I  am wrong and the problem is in the http server. Maybe it just can't give me pages faster. How to check it?

Comment: Maybe you could consider using Apache's HTTP client, this would help reading inputs faster if you read from a same server which supports keepalive. Other than that, you should open any stream in front of a try block and close it in finally, otherwise you leak file descriptors.

Comment: Forgot to say, every saved html file is 16-20 kbytes. They are barely the same size.
Samuel, thanks for editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can time your code and find out how long each method is taking to execute by doing something like this:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
methodToTime();
long endTime = System.nanoTime();

long duration = endTime - startTime;
```

Then print it out somewhere.

Source: [How do I time a method's execution in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java)

Comment: I'am already done that before asking. And i see that reading http is times slower then html file saving. That's why i ask about reading http, not saving html. Duration says every page need to read about .2 seconds. But i don't know maybe it is http server is too slow, not method of reading pages from it. Also, i have noted that pages reading .2 +- .1 seconds, but one of 5-10 files read is way too slower, i.e. 1or 2 seconds. Why is that?

Comment: @RiantHoff Probably because that page is significantly bigger than the others.

Answer (score 0):

You usually have somewhat high latency reading html (proxies etc.). However a decent webserver  can handle a lot of requests concurrently.

In order to get more throughput you should execute several http reads **concurrently** (use a threadpool).

Depending on the server used, you'll increase your throughput by 10..20 times (also depends wether your client OS is not limited in number of connections).