# Fastest way to determine list size

Tags: java

I need to know if my arraylist has 10 slots or not. Would it be a faster function to call for the size, or just as for the 10th index? Also is there any kind of way for me to check the speed of certain functions? Kind of like how phpMyAdmin can show you the time it takes to do a query.

```
if(strideList.size() == 10)
{

}
```

OR

```
if(strideList.get(9) != null)
{

}
```

Comment: I think this is relevant [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it so important to have this size check go as quickly as possible? Moreover, why is it worth sacrificing the ability to ensure that the size is *exactly* 10 in order to get the speed gain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [`ArrayList.java` source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java) (other `List` implementations will be similar), `size()` just returns an `int` member variable from the object. `get()`, however, does a range check, goes through 3 or 4 functions of overhead, then does an array access which is going to take even more processing power.

Use `size()`.

*(Plus, as [@Barış Uşaklı](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583363/baris-usakli) said, it's more readable with `size()`.)*

Answer (score 4):

You should use `list.size()` because that clearly shows your intent. The other piece of code is actually wrong what if the list has 20 elements? `strideList.get(9) != null` just checks if the ninth element is different than `null`.

As for checking the speed of functions, you can use timers to calculate the amount of time passed from the beginning to the end of a function or use special software called profilers to  see which functions/code paths are slow in your application.

Comment: there is no way the list could have more then 10 elements. I populate the list within a loop. knowing this would the latter be the best option?

Comment: No I would still use the easier to read version `size`. Don't worry about optimizing your code until you know that this piece is the bottleneck. Make it work, then make it readable, then if it is not fast enough for the job optimize.

Answer (score 1):

The strideList.get(9) will throw a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and will take more time than `list.size()` 
However point to be noted is the code for `get(int index)`. There are two steps involved
1. rangeCheck which just matches the size which you get out of `size()`
2. If the range is greater than size , it throws the Exception,which is additional time taken
3. If the size is not greater than size , then it will get from Array.
Code for ArrayList :

```
    public E get(int index) {
    382           rangeCheck(index);
    383   
    384           return elementData(index);
    385       }

  private void rangeCheck(int index) {
   603           if (index >= size)
   604               throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
   605       }
   606   


     E elementData(int index) {
      371           return (E) elementData[index];
      372       }
      373
```

Comment: Thank you. I dindn't even think of the index out of bounds!

Comment: *"I dindn't even think of the index out of bounds!"* - Well if you don't know what a method does, you should read the javadocs.