# Is scientific notation interpreted as int or float?

Tags: java, int, scientific-notation

If I hardcode a number in my code using the scientific notation (e.g. `1e9`) what will the type of that number be (int, long, float, double..)?

When the significand or the exponent are floating point numbers it can't be an integer obviously, but what in the above case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `e` makes it a floating-point literal. From the JLS ([§3.10.2. Floating-Point Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2)):

> A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is `double` and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter `D` or `d` (§4.2.3).

Therefore, `1e9` of type `double`, as is `1e9d`. On the other hand, `1e9f` is of type `float`.

Answer (score 5):

These will usually be of type **double**.
If you put an `f` (of `F`) behind it, it's a float.

```
double d = 1e9; 
float f = 1e9f;
```

Answer (score 4):

It will be considered as a [floating point literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2), and without a trailing `f` or `F` it will be a `double`.

[Integer literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) can't use scientific notation.

Answer (score 3):

It'll be 'double' unless you use 'f' or 'F' then it'll be float literal.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use Double. Because a it has decimal floating point is a computer arithmetic system closely related to scientific notation.
for example:
0.000 000 007 51
in scientific notation it is 7.51×10-9.
when you use it as int, 7.51 would be 7 while when you use int it will be 7.51.