# get the Time consumed by a method

Tags: java

what i want to do is to find the the time consumed by firing a certain method so i am using System.currentTimeMillis() before and after the method then get the difference but, is there other way since getting the currentTimeMillis is also time consumable and i am working on increasing the performance of a certain protocol.
here what i have did

```
public void someMethod
{
long x=System.currentTimeMillis();
... my bussiness
long y=System.currentTimeMillis();
int timeConsucmed =y-x;

}
```

Comment: That is a common approach.

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java). The answers do have `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()`, but one of the questions mentions using a profiler, which is probably the better option for you if you want more accurate execution timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend using [codahale's metrics](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/) and use the [`timer` functionality](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/core/).

Comment: the links are broken ...

Comment: @JimHawkins Thanks! updated link.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing for this for testing a single method use the method which you are using ..otherwise go for this library,If you are doing this multiple times.

[**Java™ Execution Time Measurement Library**](http://jetm.void.fm/)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't cost much, at most 1-2 microsecond. If you want you can change it to

```
public void someMethod
{
   //my bussiness
}
```

from whereever you are calling

```
long x=System.currentTimeMillis();

someMethod();

long y=System.currentTimeMillis();
int timeConsucmed =y-x;
```