# Code running time

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime

For some time now I have been using `System.nanoTime()` in order to measure the time it takes for code to complete. Recently this has become a great disturbance for me. Are there any other ways to measure it?

I am running Java in Eclipse.

Comment: How is it a "great disturbance"?

Comment: @Quincunx It works fine most of the time, but there was that one time it blew up Alderaan.

Comment: SO consensus seems to be that your current method (using `nanoTime()`) is fine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;    

long time = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadCpuTime(Thread.currentThread().getId())
```

[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try StatsD:

https://github.com/youdevise/java-statsd-client

Example from the README:

```
statsd.recordExecutionTime("bag", 25);
```

`bag` is the method you would like to record time.

Answer (score 0):

If you dislike typing it out every time, make a class to time it.

Example (static because I'm very lazy; don't want to instantiate an Object):

```
public static class CodeTimer{
    static long start;
    public static void start(){
        start = System.nanoTime();
    }
    public static void end(){
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - end);
        //could easily change it to print out time in seconds, with some
        //String before it, to return a value, etc.
    }
}
```

This is exactly the same as the `System.nanoTime()` method, but now you only need to type `CodeTimer.start()` at the beginning and `CodeTimer.end()` at the end.