# NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Platform.systemNanoTime() In GWT project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, guava

I get an exception in a gwt project where I'm using the `systemNanoTime()`

```
... threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Platform.systemNanoTime()J
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    ........
```

I'm using guava-18. jar in Java Build Path.

Comment: According to the javadoc of Guava, there isn't even a class named `Platform`...

Comment: If your are talking about the **guava-gwt-18.0.jar** you're right but I'm using **guava-18.0.jar** where  the Platform class exist,

Comment: Well, [the javadoc disagrees](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/index.html). Or this means there is a specific version of Guava for the app engine or something like that.

Comment: @fge: `Platform` is a package-private class some Guava packages have. Guava's Javadoc doesn't include package-private stuff since users can't use it. And guava-gwt does have the `Platform` classes as well, since they basically exist to allow different versions of methods between GWT and normal Java.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem was that I'm using the **google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar** and **guava-18.0.jar** in Java Build Path for the same project so I had to removed the google-collect

Comment: Both have `com.google.common.base.Platform`, why it always choose `Platform` in another jar