# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Platform.systemNanoTime()J

Tags: java, google-cloud-sql

I want connect to google cloud Sql form java to  this error main program while running my code i have this error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLNonTransientConnectionException,
            IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String instanceConnectionName = "****";
    String databaseName = "***";
    String IP_of_instance = "***";
    String username = "***";
    String password = "****";
    String jdbcUrl = String.format(
            "jdbc:mysql://%s/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s"
            + "&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false",
            IP_of_instance,
            databaseName,
            instanceConnectionName);

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);

    try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i got this error while running my code :

> **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Platform.systemNanoTime()J**

this is my pom file i added the dependency but still i cant access that class

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.69</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.httprpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>httprpc</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [START servlet] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [END servlet] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-urlshortener</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev57-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.healthmarketscience.sqlbuilder</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlbuilder</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [START_EXCLUDE] -->
    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.69</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.69</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-tools-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.69</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.30.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.5-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
        <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
        <version>0.42</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13-beta-1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- Only used locally -->
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.42</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [END_EXCLUDE] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This may be caused by different Guava versions conflicting. If that error happens at runtime, could you tell us how your code is packaged?

Comment: so what i have to do to resolve this please suggest me..

Comment: How is your code packaged? Is it a fat JAR? What Guava version is embedded with your application at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Verify if you are using the google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar and j ava-18.0.jar in Java Build Path for the same project please remove the google-collect

Here is the source;

[NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Platform.systemNanoTime() In GWT project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395810/nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-platform-systemnanotime-in-gwt-proje)