# Which instruction executes faster

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout

I want to execute one of the following java instructions on android several times so i want to know which approach is better for performance
Switch between

```
View.setBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
```

And

```
View.setBackgroundColor(Color.White);
```

Or between

```
View.setVisibility(View.Invisible);
```

And

```
View.setVisivility(View.Visible);
```

I only care about performance for this task

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java

Comment: Thanks for that link

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking the alternatives​?

Comment: Remember if you do such a benchmark that android is relayouting and redrawing not immediately. So benchmarking the execution time of  `View.setVisivility(View.Visible)`  doesn't give you any concrete result. you have to benchmark the time it takes before you apply the change until the next frame has drawn where your changes has been applied.

I don't think the performance difference is relevant at all. Better spend your dev time with something else.

Also the color "solution" doesn't seem to be user friendly (i.e. you might also have to remove click listeners etc.)

Comment: How can i know when the frame is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

There was a very similar question before... I think you should be asking about View.GONE, though. Or entirely removing the view from the content altogether

Obviously setting a color or visibility doesn't affect anything other than what you see. There is no performance gain from either option.

The real performance  you get is to not cause a layout to be entirely redrawn

Comment: If the view is gone then another view may take its place i want to avoid that i just want to affect what i see

Comment: Only if you're using a relative position

Comment: Yes it sometimes does it