# I have an efficient algorithm to find the maximum integer in an array of millions, need advice on these two

Tags: java

Which is better to use for an array of millions of integers(ages)

```
public static int findMax(int[] x) {
    int max = 0;
    int curr = 0;
    for (int a : x) {
        curr = Math.max(curr, a);
        max = Math.max(max, curr);
    }
    return max;
}
public static int findMax(int[] x){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int y : x){
        list.add(y);
    }
    return Collections.max(list);
}
```

Comment: What do you think. Explain precisely what happens in both cases. And explain what the role of `curr` is in the first version. Also think about what happens if all numbers are negative.

Comment: @CupofJava because that would be much more expensive than it needs to be.

Comment: The first version would give wrong results if all the numbers in the array are negative.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I don't think they have negative numbers since they are ages.

Comment: Both are in O(N) So they are equivalent. But in practice the second one will be slower because it needs to copy the array.

Comment: Consider also `Arrays.stream(x).max()`. You can parallelize it too.

Comment: @litelite i also thought the second one does too many operations, hence i asked for advice

Comment: @RealSkeptic, i have code for edge cases, although ages cannot be negative i just wanted to make sure this is as efficient as possible

Comment: @JBNizet Is there a difference? `IntStream.of` just calls `Arrays.stream`.

Comment: @user1803551 no, you're absolutely right. I missed the fact that Arrays.stream() was overloaded for primitive arrays.

Comment: Not a coding thought, but it's better to ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one will definitely be faster than the second one, as you really don't want to be making an arraylist for no reason just to find the maximum of an array!

Also, there is no reason to use two different variables for the current and the max, just the max will suffice, like so:

```
public static int findMax(int[] x) {
  int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  for (int a : x) {
      max = Math.max(max, a);
  }
  return max;
}
```

Note: I used the minimum integer because the largest value in your array may be negative. Also, you could just use an if-condition instead of Math.max(), but it'll work either way. This also saves you an extra operation. The runtime is O(n) in every case.

Comment: Perfect, i especially like the generalization of the solution. Thank you, i just used it to efficiently find the min as well

Comment: @EastXWest If you're looking for a practical way to find the maximum then you'd have to consider parallel algorithms. If you're looking for theoretical solutions this is fine.

Comment: @EastXWest It's a huge topic with tons of resources. Have a quick read at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_algorithm). Since almost all CPUs today have more than 1 physical core, you can leverage this to run an algorithm on multiple cores at once, which will be much faster. The simplest example would be to split the array into 2, have each core run the sequential algorithm and then combine the results. That's about twice as fast obviously. Java also has built in implementations a la [fork-join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork–join_model).

Comment: Thanks @user1803551, i have found it, i was a bit out of it i see what you mean now. I am grateful. Do't know why i didn't consider this. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

They both look like they are O(n). You could always use a logger and see what the time is. The following is a link that talks about logging time executed: [How do I time a method's execution in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java)

Comment: Appreciate the link

Comment: Both O(n) but one does a lot of useless allocation before getting to the actual work.