# does java have similar tool like timeit of Python

Tags: java, benchmarking

Python has a `timeit` module could use it to time code execution, e.g.

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:sleep(0.1), number=10)
1.02257220899628
```

Does in java have similar tool could time code execution as `timeit`, e.g.

```
@Timeit(number=10)
@Test
public void foo(){
    service.foo();
}
```

Comment: For short running parts (i.e. microbenchmarks), there is the [Java Microbenchmark Harness](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) ([Tutorial by Jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html))

Comment: Since you seem to want to use it on a test: JUnit has a [timeout annotation](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/Timeout.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  You can create a wrapper class using System.nanoTime().

Also, there is a similar Stack overflow question with answers posted here:
[How do I time a method's execution in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java)

Also of use: a very rudimentary implementation:
[Timeit.java](https://github.com/jbbarquero/learn-java8/blob/master/src/main/java/com/malsolo/learn/java8/Timeit.java)

Answer (score 0):

[Metrics](http://metrics.dropwizard.io) could provide what you're looking for. But it might be a bit overkill in most cases.