# Date object will return 1537865065664 on two Difference Date Object in java

Tags: java, date

I want time difference in second using new Date().getTime() in java.
But i will return me long digit like this 1537865065664.
How can i get difference between two Date() object.
I will attached few part of my code below.

```
     Date starttime=new Date();
      long diff=  new Date().getTime() - starttime.getTime()
 System.out.println("hangupClicked New Time :: "+new Date().getTime()+" :: "+starttime.getTime());
```

Output :: 
hangupClicked New Time :: 1537865248609 :: 1537865348612

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` is an ineffecient way of doing `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: Is this what you want? [How do I time a method's execution in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java) Also I didn’t really get your problem. Your calculation of the difference looks correct, but you are not printing the difference.

Comment: And why use `Date`? The `Date` class is long outdated and has a greater number of design problems. I recommend you either use `System.currentTimeMillis()` and then `TimeUnit` for conversion to seconds, or still nicer `Instant` and `Duration` for finding the difference and converting to seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The difference obtained using date1.getTime() - date2.getTime() is in milliseconds. You can divide the output by 1000 to get difference in seconds.

```
(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())/1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

new Date().getTime() returns time in milliseconds. So if you want in seconds, you need to divide the difference by 1000.

```
 Date starttime=new Date();
  long diff=  (new Date().getTime() - starttime.getTime())/1000;
```

Comment: Still I got hangupClicked differenceInSeconds :: 100
hangupClicked New Time :: 1537873474080 :: 1537873374061

Comment: new Date().getTime() returns  ==> 1537865065664

Comment: How does `differenceInSeconds :: 100` differ from your expected or desired result? Which result do you want? @Rahul

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

```
    Instant startTime = Instant.now();
    Duration diff = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());
    System.out.println("Difference in seconds: " + diff.getSeconds());
```

This snippet just printed:

```
Difference in seconds: 0
```

This is as expected since there isn’t a full second between the two calls to `Instant.now()`.

### What went wrong in your code?

You were calculating the difference in milliseconds between your two `Date` objects correctly. You did not print the difference and therefore never saw that it was correct. And you did not convert it to seconds.

To illustrate the first point I added this line to your code:

```
    System.out.println("diff (milliseconds):: " + diff);
```

Then I got this output from it:

```
hangupClicked New Time :: 1537890219204 :: 1537890219204
diff (milliseconds):: 0
```

That said, you shouldn’t use `Date` in 2018. That class is long outdated and poorly designed at the same time. You should prefer to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) on Jon Skeet’s coding blog

Answer (score 0):

**If you want in second then divide the diff by 1000 then you will get in second. Date().getTime() return the value in milliseconds.**

Answer (score 0):

The return type of **getTime()** is milliseconds from 01-01-1970 to the specified date. So in order to get difference in seconds use below

```
(date.getTime() - date2.getTime())/1000;
```

Comment: Still I got hangupClicked differenceInSeconds :: 100
hangupClicked New Time :: 1537873474080 :: 1537873374061

Comment: new Date().getTime() returns  ==> 1537865065664

Comment: Date starttime=new Date();
     long diff=  (new Date().getTime() - starttime.getTime())/1000;  System.out.println(" Difference in seconds "+diff);