# Time how long a function runs (short duration)

Tags: java, time, benchmarking, nanotime

I'm relatively new to Java programming, and I'm running into an issue calculating the amount of time it takes for a function to run.

First some background - I've got a lot of experience with Python, and I'm trying to recreate the functionality of the Jupyter Notebook/Lab `%%timeit` function, if you're familiar with that. Here's a pic of it in action (sorry, not enough karma to embed yet):

[Snip of Jupyter %%timeit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMAqV.png)

What it does is run the contents of the cell (in this case a recursive function) either 1k, 10k, or 100k times, and give you the average run time of the function, and the standard deviation.

My first implementation (using the same recursive function) used `System.nanoTime()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long t1, t2, diff;
    long[] times = new long[1000];
    int t;
    for (int i=0; i< 1000; i++) {

        t1 = System.nanoTime();
        t = triangle(20);
        t2 = System.nanoTime();

        diff = t2-t1;
        System.out.println(diff);
        times[i] = diff;
    }

    long total = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<times.length; j++) {
        total += times[j];
    }
    System.out.println("Mean = " + total/1000.0);
}
```

But the mean is wildly thrown off -- for some reason, the first iteration of the function (on many runs) takes upwards of a million nanoseconds:

[Pic of initial terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3t0Z.png)

Every iteration after the first dozen or so takes either 395 nanos or 0 -- so there could be a problem there too... not sure what's going on!

Also -- the code of the recursive function I'm timing:

```
static int triangle(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return n + triangle(n -1);
    }
}
```

Initially I had the line `n = Math.abs(n)` on the first line of the function, but then I removed it because... meh. I'm the only one using this.

I tried a number of different suggestions brought up in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java), but they each have their own problems... which I can go into if you need.

Anyway, thank you in advance for your help and expertise!

Comment: JIT. Warm up. Benchmarking is hard. System clocks don't really do nano second resolution. What platform is this anyway? Which version of Java, which JRE, which operating system, what results do you expect?

Comment: Using JDK10 + the JRE that came with it -- running on Windows 10. Is there a better timer to use? I tried the `Instant` and `Duration` ones mentioned in that other post, same problem there too. Edit: does the JVM come with its own timer?

Comment: Like [python's `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) (which you attributed to Jupyter)? No. But there is [`StopWatch`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/StopWatch.html) in [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).

Comment: I should have said -- does the JVM come with its own internal clock that I can reach out to, if the system clock is a bad way to go about this. I was referring to the Jupyter magic command, which uses the [python `timeit`](https://img.memecdn.com/you-got-me_o_1891513.jpg) function, yes.

Comment: `System.nanoTime` is the right method to use. You get nothing preciser. Related: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: Awesome -- thank you!