# How to calculate the runtime of this function?

Tags: java, recursion, runtime, binary-tree

I am trying to calculate the runtime of a function I wrote in Javq, I wrote a function that calculates the sum of all the right children in a BT.

I used recursion in the function, and I don't really understand how to calculate the runtime in recursion non the less in a BT (just started studying the subject).

This is the code I wrote:

```
public int sumOfRightChildren(){
    return sumOfRightChildren(this.root);
}

private int sumOfRightChildren(Node root){
    if(root == null) //O(1)
        return 0;//O(1)
    int sum = 0;//O(1)
    if(root.right != null)//O(1)
        sum+=root.right.data;//O(1)
    sum += sumOfRightChildren(root.right); //worst case O(n) ?
    if(root.left != null)
    {
       sum += sumOfRightChildren(root.left);//worst case O(n)?
    }
    return  sum;
}
```

I tried writing down the runtimes I think it takes, but I don't think I am doing it right.
If someone can help guide me I'd be very thankful.

I'm trying to calculate T(n).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I time a method's execution in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java)

Comment: Not really I'm trying to calculate T(n) mathematically.

Comment: How come does it not help you? You`ll get the execution time in nanoseconds and then you convert to regular seconds or whatever you need it in

Comment: I am trying to find the worst case runtime. Umm like in witch family of functions (n,n^2,nlogn,logn...) this function is in.
Like in the first recursion call I made I want to know how to write it mathematically like:
T(n) = T(n-1)+5 
and figure out the worst case runtime.
Not literality get the amount of time it took it to run.

Comment: In other words I'm trying to find the mathematical expression for the recursion call's in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you visit every node exactly once is easy to see the runtime cost is **T(n) = n * K** where **n** is the number of nodes in the Binary Tree and **K** is the expected function cost.

If you want to **explicitly** consider the cost of certain operations you may not be able to calculate it exactly (without having an input example). For example, calculating the number of times `sum+=...` is executed is not possible because it depends on the particular tree.

In this case the worst case is a **full** Binary Tree and, if it is **n=1,2,...** their depth:

1. the complexity is **O(2^n)** (no matter the operations since all of them take **O(1)** as you have posted).
2. the cost of `sum+=root.right.data;` is **T(n) = 2^n - 1** (all internal nodes).
3. the cost of `sum+=...` is **T(n) = 3 * (2^n - 1)** (twice for every internal node and one more for each node).
4. ...

(NOTE: the exact final expression may vary since your `if(root.left != null)` is not usefull and prefereable let that condition to the `if(root == null)`)

Comment: Ohh Okay I understand now. thanks for the help I appreciate it very much

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I understood,
The worst case is that is has to check all the nodes in the tree so the answer is: O(n)

Comment: Note that **T(n)** (your question) is not the same that **O(n)** (your answer).

Comment: remember to accept his answer if it solves your issue

Comment: Doesn't mean that T(n) is in O(n)?
T(n) <= O(n)
where n is the number of elements in the tree