# best approach to measure time of running code

Tags: java

I want to measure time (like stopwatch) of some code, what I did so far is :

```
TimeWatch watch = new TimeWatch();
watch = TimeWatch.start();
some code
double passedTimeInSeconds = (watch.time(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) / 1000.0;
```

does these is the best option and the correct option to calculate the times?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I time a method's execution in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java)

Comment: does each time I call the start method its start from zero to count the time?


`import com.google.common.base.Stopwatch;

Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.createStarted();
//method invocation
LOG.info("Method took: " + timer.stop());`